# How to find the first index in array of dictionaries whereby the 'name' key begins with a certain letter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsarray, nsdictionary

OK this ones had me stumped for a while.

How can I find the first index in my Array of Dictionaries whereby the key begins with the letter provided?

My array contains 2500 dictionaries, each have a name, longitude and latitude key. Say I have the letter @"S" how do I find the index for the first dictionary in the array whereby the value for the key 'name' begins with S?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` (it provides a `stop` `BOOL` so you can easily stop the iteration). Inside the block, get the name from the dictionary. Assuming you want an exact match with the source string against the start of the name, use `hasPrefix:` to check. Set the stop flag when you get a match.

Comment: Or use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`, if only the first match is needed.

Comment: I'd forgotten about indexOfObjectPassingTest, you could be a life saver there! It is just literally just an NSInteger for the index of the first match that I need.